# Angular 6 component NgModule

Tags: angular

I work with Angular 6. I have the following ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// debugger;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

I have the following error

```
Component 'AppComponent' is not included in a module and will not be available inside a template. Consider adding it to a NgModule declaration
```

I have the definition of a NgModule

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { ProductComponent } from "./component";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    declarations: [ProductComponent],
    bootstrap: [ProductComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Do I have to include AppComponent in this NgModule?

Answer (score 0):

First you should import AppComponent in "app.module.ts" and after that you should declare it and add it in bootstrap like this:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { ProductComponent } from "./component";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Component 'AppComponent' is not included in a module and will not be
>   available inside a template. Consider adding it to a NgModule
>   declaration

**Fix:** If you are not using AppComponent anywhere and bootstraping your application with ProductComponent instead, just remove the selectors 'app-root' from any html file that includes it(I suspect index.html file in your root directory)

Or if you indeed want to use it, you would have to import AppComponent in you app.module.ts and declare it in the Declarations array of NgModule decorator as well.

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { ProductComponent } from "./component";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";      // import it here
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    declarations: [ProductComponent, AppComponent],    //declare it here
    bootstrap: [ProductComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using selector of AppComponent (usually **app-root**) anywhere in your Application please remove that As it is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking this questtion, you are new to angular 2+.
FYI:

- Any new component that we created should be configured (added) in
  **declarations** array near by ngModule. In your case it is app.module.ts.
- Any new service or pipe that we created should be configured (added) in **providers** array near by ngModule. In your case it is
  app.module.ts.

Sample app.modules.ts looks like below

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BillingComponent } from './billing/billing.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { rootRouterConfig } from './app.route';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CustomersComponent } from './customers/customers.component';
import { GasStorageComponent } from './gas-storage/gas-storage.component';

import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    BillingComponent,
    CustomersComponent,
    GasStorageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig),
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to first import the component in your app module and then add the app component in the declarations array

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import { ProductComponent } from "./component";
    import {AppComponent} from './components/app.component'
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

    @NgModule({
        imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
        declarations: [ProductComponent,AppComponent],
        bootstrap: [ProductComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `AppComponent` in that module in which you want to use it. If you bootstrap 
`ProductComponent` and use `AppComponent` inside it, you need to add those one into that module in which you have used `ProductComponent`.